# Golang testcontainers vs Azure Devops pipelines: Containers killed randomly?

Tags: go, azure-pipelines, testcontainers

while implemening and running my database integration tests with golang testcontainers works like a charm locally, it seems my tests are randomly not working in azure devops pipelines.

Pipeline logs show this:

```
2023/01/09 16:06:02 (...) Error: read tcp 127.0.0.1:52546->127.0.0.1:49161: read: connection reset by peer
```

After adding container logging, improveing the waiting criteria, removing the usage of db container config files (so I dont have to copy files into the container) and disabling Ryuk, I am wondering what else needs to be done, or if I am initializing the containers incorrect.

For every unittest, the testcontainers are started like this:

```
func SetupTestDatabase(ctx context.Context) (testcontainers.Container, project.Repository, error) {
    containerReq := testcontainers.ContainerRequest{
        SkipReaper:   true,
        Image:        "postgres:11.18-alpine3.17",
        ExposedPorts: []string{"5432/tcp"},
        Cmd:          []string{"postgres", "-c", "fsync=off"},
        Env: map[string]string{
            "POSTGRES_DB":         "postgre",
            "POSTGRES_PASSWORD":   "postgres",
            "POSTGRES_USER":       "postgres",
            "PGUSER":              "postgres",
            "POSTGRES_EXTENSIONS": "uuid-ossp",
        },
    }

    containerReq.WaitingFor = wait.ForAll(
        wait.ForListeningPort("5432/tcp"),
        wait.ForExec([]string{"pg_isready", "-t 10", "-q"}), // postgre docs: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/app-pg-isready.html
    ).WithDeadline(3 * time.Minute)

    dbContainer, err := testcontainers.GenericContainer(
        ctx,
        testcontainers.GenericContainerRequest{
            ContainerRequest: containerReq,
            Started:          true,
        })
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("Database container could not be started. Error: %s", err)
        return nil, nil, errors.WithStack(err)
    }

    err = dbContainer.StartLogProducer(ctx)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("Logproducer could not be started. Error: %s", err)
        return nil, nil, errors.WithStack(err)
    }
    defer dbContainer.StopLogProducer()
    lc := logConsumer{}
    dbContainer.FollowOutput(&lc)

    port, err := dbContainer.MappedPort(ctx, "5432")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("Mapped port could not be retrieved. Error: %s", err)
        return nil, nil, errors.WithStack(err)
    }
    host, err := dbContainer.Host(ctx)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("Hostname could not be retrieved. Error: %s", err)
        return nil, nil, errors.WithStack(err)
    }

    global.Config.Postgres.Host = host
    global.Config.Postgres.Port = port.Port()
    global.Config.Postgres.User = "postgres"
    global.Config.Postgres.Password = "postgres"
    global.Config.Postgres.DbName = "postgre"
    global.Config.Local = true

    global.Logger = logger.NewNull(config.Config{
        Logging: config.Logging{
            Level: "debug",
        },
    })

    repository, err := New(ctx)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("Repository could not be setup. Error: %s", err)
        return nil, nil, errors.WithStack(err)
    }

    return dbContainer, repository, nil
}
```

... the creation of the repository with `repository, err := New(ctx)` towards the end uses migrate to setup the database analog to our productive ones and gorm for the db connection and handling et al.

The basic template for a unittest is:

```
func Test_pg_Has(t *testing.T) {
    ctx := context.TODO()
    dbContainer, repository, err := SetupTestDatabase(ctx)
    if err != nil {
        t.Errorf("error running testcontainers, error: %s", err)
    }
    t.Cleanup(func() {
        if err := dbContainer.Terminate(ctx); err != nil {
            t.Fatalf("failed to terminate container: %s", err)
        }
        time.Sleep(10 * time.Second)
    })
    
    ... TEST_CODE
}
```

For the Azure Pipeline, stock Azure Agent Pools are used, GO in version "1.18.0 x64".

Any hint is appreciated, thank you in advance.

Comment: Can you provide more info about the azure pipeline config?

Comment: @EddúMeléndez: Yes, sure, I added some informatino on the bootom of the Thread. What else is needed? Currently thinking about setting up a simplified public example for testing.

Comment: @chrispolzer is it possible that the cmd args passed to the wait.ForExec is not totally correct? 

`[]string{"pg_isready", "-t", "10", "-q"}`

instead of

`[]string{"pg_isready", "-t 10", "-q"}`

Comment: i tried several different versions of this...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a quite unsatisfing solution, I added a 5 seconds sleep after the container is created, just before I set up the db connection.

It might be a Azure Devops specific problems as we discovered that even unittests running in one single container randomly fail.

Accepting this as response is also kind of a challenge for the community...